# Join blocks at the corners (Starter Block)

Tags: animation

I want to match two blocks at the corners. If I hold CTRL the block is moving in steps but i want that the block attaches to the other. Thx for our help.

Comment: your question is not clear, is it for an animation? could you please show pictures of what is supposed to happen at start and end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set what type of snapping you want in the snapping pop-over.

[image]